# Taleo Import - way to do import without applying changes to system

Tags: taleo, taleo-connect-client

We are trying to find a way to check the TCC import process but without applying the changes into the system. This is to allow us to capture all the possible kickouts and correct those. We want to load the file into Taleo in one shot without doing multiple tries.